# How to use CHtml's link function without linking to 'index'?

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager, yii-chtml

I'm using the `CHtml::link()` function, and I have a problem with the index action.

The code in view:

```
echo CHtml::link('Watch it', array('video/index', 'id' => $id));
```

The urlManager part in config:

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'rules' => array(
            '<id>/<action>' => 'video/<action>',
            '<id>' => 'video/index'
        )
    )
```

What I want it to do is to create a link to:

```
http://localhost/123
```

Instead, it creates a link to:

```
http://localhost/123/index
```

How can I remove the '/index' part?

Creating a function that will handle this (replace '/index' with nothing) will be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Yii::app()->createUrl in chtml link function

```
echo CHtml::link('Watch it', Yii::app()->createUrl('video/index', 'id' => $id));
```

UPD Try this

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'rules' => array( 
            '<id>' => 'video/index'
            '<id>/<action>' => 'video/<action>',

        )
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it creates the same link.

Comment: @user3803707 I just tested and this solution worked for me. Rather, just the rules change was sufficient, the `createUrl` method is unnecessary. Did you notice styopdev swapped the order of the rules?